# Asp.net jQuery Ajax - unable to pass image data from img tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, asp.net-ajax

I have been trying to pass image from img tag and other form details from webform using jQuery Ajax call to store it in DB as a blob . I am converting the image into base64 string which is too large text. All other text fields data is being passed through Ajax call. But when an image is there in img tag and I try to pass it to server side through Ajax , the Ajax call is not working. The page simply reloads and call doesn't reach the back end function code to save.

Kindly guide me to resolve this issue whether converting to base 64 using toDataURI is recommended is there any other way to send the image to back end . It a not a image uploaded using file upload. It's image which is clicked from web cam and tagged to source of img tag